# How do I increase the session time-out in ASP.NET Core? Already have web.config and session IdleTimeout

Tags: asp.net-core

**Please read before marking as a duplicate**

I have an ASP.NET 6 Core Blazor server-side application, which will be used from an intranet, so timing out the sessions is not necessary and annoys the users. I would like to increase the time-out to (say) 12 hours, which allows them to log in when they arrive in the morning, and stay logged in all day.

Following the main questions here on the subject, I have the following `Web.Config` file...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"
      encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore"
           path="*"
           verb="*"
           modules="AspNetCoreModule"
           resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="12:00:00"
                processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%"
                arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"
                stdoutLogEnabled="false"
                stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
                forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I also added the following to `program.cs`...

```cs
builder.Services.AddSession(opt => {
  opt.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
  opt.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
  opt.Cookie.IsEssential = false;
});
```

However, despite all this, the app still times out after about 20 minutes.

What am I doing wrong? THanks

Comment: [increasing-session-timeout-in-aspnet-core-web-app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/827217/increasing-session-timeout-in-aspnet-core-web-app.html)

Comment: @RyanWilson Thanks for that. Do you want to add the code there as an answer and I'll mark it?

Comment: If what fixed your issue was changing the settings in `IIS` then you should add that tag to your question as it's not really a coding issue, but a configuration issue.

Comment: @RyanWilson Nope, this web site isn't deployed yet. This is all inside Visual Studio. Thanks again.